# Duplicanting XCode project gives me the old myproject.app

Tags: xcode4

I have duplicated my project by copying and pasting the folders.

Then inside the project I renamed the project name so it pops a window asking to rename the target.

I've done this twice before with no problems, but this time, inside the Products folder the myproject.app file is still the old one.

The new one does not appear on my scheme options, so I don't know what else to do.

Xcode complains about an icon file that doesn't exist anymore.

Is there anyway to fix it; is there some other way to duplicate projects?

Comment: Actually I solved it. I forgot to change the "Product Name" on Target Build Settings.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark as correct for the communities future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for duplicating a project with XCode 4.2 is copying and pasting the project folder then opening the new one.

Click once on the project name on the left (Project Navigator), then rename it.

You will be prompted to rename whatever targets you have. Just click rename.

Then on your target build settings change the Product Name property.