# Duplicating the iOS xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have copied the existing project and changed the name of the project, info.plist, and product name, targets. I wanted to create the same project with different name. 
Actually this is done. The project name is changed, I have changed the name of the info.plist and the target name.

The problem I'm facing here is,

- whenever I run the newly copied app on my simulator, it opens up the old app.
- If I try deleting the old app. this newly created app doesnot open up. just say app is running. And the app is not launched on the simulator

I think some settings update have been missed out, which I'm not able to find out. Any idea what this might be.

Thanks

Comment: You need to change bundle id

Comment: Thanks... This [link: duplicating....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199288/duplicanting-xcode-project-gives-me-the-old-myproject-app) worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create different `BundleID` for your application.

If this does not work then as a workaround  try to delete the old app from the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change bundle identifier from info.plist to differentiate your app.

Answer (score -1):

Reset your simulator and try running the new app  it should work for you